# make emacs don't change the line end automatically

Tags: emacs

it's not about using the windows style line end.
I would prefer the unix style.
but I don't want emacs to change those windows line ends there for me. it is sometimes annoying for the automatic change

how to do that ?

Comment: I have to say although the Answer is long and conversation back and forth. actually this might be an issue setting on the SRC MANAGEMENT TOOL. close this anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emacs does not change the EOL characters automatically. By default it detects and uses the existing EOL characters in the file.

> Emacs recognizes which kind of end-of-line conversion to use based on the contents of the file: if it sees only carriage-returns, or only carriage-return linefeed sequences, then it chooses the end-of-line conversion accordingly.  You can inhibit the automatic use of end-of-line conversion by setting the variable `inhibit-eol-conversion'to non-`nil'.  If you do that, DOS-style files will be displayed with the `^M' characters visible in the buffer; some people prefer this to the more subtle `(DOS)' end-of-line type indication near the left edge of the mode line (*note eol-mnemonic: Mode Line.).

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs) Recognize Coding` <kbd>RET</kbd>

The current EOL encoding is indicated at the left-hand side of the mode line:

> The character after CS is usually a colon.  If a different string is displayed, that indicates a nontrivial end-of-line convention for encoding a file.  Usually, lines of text are separated by "newline characters" in a file, but two other conventions are sometimes used. The MS-DOS convention uses a "carriage-return" character followed by a "linefeed" character; when editing such files, the colon changes to either a backslash (`\') or `(DOS)', depending on the operating system. Another convention, employed by older Macintosh systems, uses a "carriage-return" character instead of a newline; when editing such files, the colon changes to either a forward slash (`/') or `(Mac)'. On some systems, Emacs displays `(Unix)' instead of the colon for files that use newline as the line separator.

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs) Mode Line` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Start Emacs with `emacs -Q` to check its default behaviour.

Comment: sorry that nearly forgot this issue, it is still there in my Emacs, really annoying. lines display correctly in windows turn into a mess after load in emacs, I have explicitly set the configure, and yet it is still not working: $(setq inhibit-eol-conversion nil)$. windows lines continue to exist as ^M .

Comment: And what is the reported EOL mode in the mode line?

Comment: -=-U:%%--F1  fix102.xml   All (1,0)     <N>  P4-2  (nXML Valid Outl Fly Abbrev)-
@phils this is the mode line, but I did set that variable to nil. how do I change the buffer to DOS type ?

Comment: Okay, so as per previous quotations, that colon (`:`) near the start means that Emacs is treating the file as having Unix-style line endings, which is why the carriage-returns (`^M`) are visible. Chances are fair that you have mixed line endings in the file. Look for files which do *not* end in `^M`.

Comment: is there a way to force emacs to treat the file as DOS coded line endings ?

Comment: Once you fix the non-DOS line endings which are confusing it, just reload the file.

Comment: Or alternatively, you could simply search and replace those `^M`s out of existence (`C-q C-m` to enter that character), then click the `:` in the mode line until it says `DOS`, and save the buffer. (I'm sure there's a better way to do that, but it should do the trick.)

Comment: I have had a very similar issue with NTemacs 24.2.1 and XML files. I think I finally have a fix: Add xml (and possibly html) files to `auto-coding-alist` and assign them to coding system `dos`.  You can use _customize_ or put this in your .emacs: `(add-to-list 'auto-coding-alist (cons "\\.\\(xml\\|x?html?\\)\\'" . dos))`  I believe that the functions in `auto-coding-functions` bypass the EOL detection - they do seem to respect a preset set via `auto-coding-alist`, though.